# gojs - Change color of node when selected, but go back to original color otherwise?

Tags: javascript, nodes, gojs

This is the node template I'm working with:

```
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
    {
      deletable: false,
      selectionAdorned: false
    },
    new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
    $(go.Shape, "Terminator",
      {
        fill: "#f8da07", strokeWidth: 2, minSize: new go.Size(90, 40), portId: "", cursor: "pointer", stroke: '#000000', fromLinkable: true,
        toLinkable: false, fromLinkableSelfNode: false, toLinkableSelfNode: false, fromLinkableDuplicates: false, toLinkableDuplicates: false, fromMaxLinks: 1
      },
      new go.Binding("figure"),
      new go.Binding("fill", "color"),
      new go.Binding("fill", "isSelected", function(sel) {
        return sel ? "#e1e1e1" : [selfColor];
      }).ofObject()),
    {
      click: (e, obj) => {
        clickNode(e, obj);
      }
    },
    $(go.TextBlock,
      {
        stroke: "#000000", margin: 4, editable: false, font: "bold 12pt sans-serif", isMultiline: true
      },
      new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
  );
```

You can see that the default color for the node is #f8da07, but it is actually being written by the node self color property with the line "new go.Binding("fill", "color")".

And as it is, I have no way of knowing which one is the current color code of the node being selected.

I want to be able to change the color of the node to "#e1e1e1" when I select it, but I also want it to change back to the old color when not  - (which is NOT "#f8da07").

Is there a proper way to do this?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(go.Shape,
  { fill: "#f8da07" },  // default color
  new go.Binding("fill", "color"),
  new go.Binding("fill", "isSelected", function(sel, shape) {
    return sel ? "#e1e1e1" : shape.part.data.color || "#f8da07";
  }).ofObject()),
```

Comment: When writing it, I get the error: Property 'part' does not exist on type 'GraphObject | RowColumnDefinition'...

Comment: Nevermind, adding:  function (sel, shape: go.GraphObject)  did it.
This works like a charm. Thanks!